# How to set sqs:SendMessages permission to send SNS messages to SQS using AWS CLI commands in a .bat file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, aws-cli, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm trying to automate the creation of several AWS services using one .bat file. Right now I'm trying to create some standard SQS queues each subscribed to a standard SNS topic. I can successfully create the topics, queues and subscriptions, however I'm having troubles setting the permissions via CLI with the right batch syntax. So far I've done something like:

```
@echo off

set region=us-east-1
set account_id=123456789012

@echo Creating SNS topics
aws sns create-topic --name some-topic

@echo Creating SQS queues
aws sqs create-queue --queue-name some-queue

@echo Subscribing queues to topics
aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:%region%:%account_id%:some-topic --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint arn:aws:sqs:%region%:%account_id%:some-queue

@echo Adding publishing permissions to SNS and SQS
aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url https://sqs.%region%.amazonaws.com/account_id/some-queue --attributes Policy= "{'Version':'2012-10-17','Statement':[{'Effect':'Allow','Principal':{'AWS':'*'},'Action':'sqs:SendMessage','Resource':'arn:aws:sqs:%region%:%account_id%:some-topic','Condition':{'ArnEquals':{'aws:SourceArn':'arn:aws:sns:%region%:%account_id%:some-topic'}}}]}"
```

The first 3 commands work perfectly, but I can't seem to find a simple working way of setting the permissions. I've tried several different things but none of them work. I'd appreciate any hints on the simplest way of setting these permissions from the .bat file.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific problem? Does it generate an error message? Does the Policy not get stored? Or does the command work, but SNS can't send to the SQS queue?

Answer (score 0):

The actual string you need to pass to the CLI is meant to be a string that's a JSON document.  Meaning, instead of using `'` like in your script, you need to pass `"`, but because it's treated as a string and not a JSON document, you need to pass `\"`.  Doing so involves the escaping rules of the Command Interpreter:

```
@echo Adding publishing permissions to SNS and SQS
aws sqs set-queue-attributes ^
    --region %region% ^
    --queue-url https://sqs.%region%.amazonaws.com/%account_id%/some-queue ^
    --attributes Policy="\"^
    {^
        \\\"Statement\\\": [{^
            \\\"Action\\\": \\\"sqs:SendMessage\\\",^
            \\\"Condition\\\": {^
                \\\"ArnEquals\\\": {^
                    \\\"aws:SourceArn\\\": \\\"arn:aws:sns:%region%:%account_id%:some-topic\\\"^
                }^
            },^
            \\\"Effect\\\": \\\"Allow\\\",^
            \\\"Principal\\\": {^
                \\\"AWS\\\": \\\"*\\\"^
            },^
            \\\"Resource\\\": \\\"arn:aws:sqs:%region%:%account_id%:some-topic\\\"^
        }],^
        \\\"Version\\\": \\\"2012-10-17\\\"^
    }\""
```

I've broken out this string into multiple lines with `^` escaping the newline, and surrounding the entire string with `"`.

I would generally, however, recommend moving to a different scripting language.  This solution is straightforward enough, but once you start involving cases where you need to pass '%' or '^', the rules get rather complex.